# My CSS file is not saving

Tags: html, css, sublimetext3

I'm working on a web page project, with an HTML file and a CSS file only. I use Sublime Text 3 for a better programming environment, I also use XAMPP to debug my code and test it on Chrome.

When I'm saving my programming files, the HTML one is saving, but CSS one is not saving; I checked it in the directory and opened it to view if my editions are saved or no, they are, but they don't show up in the debug using XAMPP and Chrome.

Why aren't my changes showing up in debug?

Comment: Are you sure you're debugging the newer versions of the CSS file?

Comment: Yes, i do, though i keep checking the css file using notepad after saving it on Sublime

Answer (score 0):

Try **deleting the Chrome Browser's Cache**. It might be creating that problem

Comment: From clear browsing data option, if i'm correct, right?

Answer (score 0):

fisrt try to clear/delete your browsers cache and if that didnt work try the steps below.

Lets say all your css code is in a file called `style.css`, what you need to do is:

you can just change the name of your file to something else for example `style2.css` (dont forget to also change the name in html file)

**or**

1. create a new file for example `new-style.css.`
2. copy and paste all the css code that you have from `style.css` to
   `new-style.css`.
3. and lastly just delete `style.css`.
4. after that you can rename `new-style.css` back to `style.css` Or you can
   keep it like that. doesnt really matter as long as you remember to
   change the link name in html as well.

It might not be the best way to solve this problem but it works.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't let me comment, but this is adding onto the users answer of clearing the browser cache.

Clear browser cache in chrome: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

If the issue resolves after clearing your browsing cache, what I usually do when working with stylesheets is use the Chrome browser in incognito mode, it usually doesn't store cache in that mode, so after closing the tab and revisiting, it should show all of the changes.